# SQL server join selects slower than join select with local table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

I have two very big queries with multiple selects. All selects are **JOINED** (left, inner and right joins). Example:

```
Declare @p2 Table (
...
)

Insert into @p2
    Select * from D 
          join E on D.id = E.id
          left join F on E.id2 = F.id
          ....

    Select * from(
       (Select * from A 
          join B on A.id = B.id
          join C on B.id2 = C.id
          ....
       ) as PART1
    right join  
       @p2 as PART2
    on PART1.ID = PART2.ID)
```

This code works fine and it needs about 20s to execute. I run the Execution plan and it show that 57% of time is used for inserts. In order to optimize this query I created one query like:

```
    Select * from(
       (Select * from A 
          join B on A.id = B.id
          join C on B.id2 = C.id
          ....
       ) as PART1
    right join  
       (Select * from D 
          join E on D.id = E.id
          left join F on E.id2 = F.id
          ....) as PART2
    on PART1.ID = PART2.ID)
```

I expected this will significantly increase speed but it turned out it was 4 times slower. Do you know why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not giving a lot of information to go by, so my answer is going to be very general.

When SQL Server optimizes a query it tries to find the best posible execution plan. However, for complex queries the number of possible plans is so high that an exhaustive search is not possible.

If you look at a simple two table join like `SELECT * FROM A JOIN B ON A.id = B.id;` you have 6 options to create a plan:

- A LOOP JOIN B
- A MERGE JOIN B
- A HASH JOIN B
- B LOOP JOIN A
- B MERGE JOIN A
- B HASH JOIN A

This does not even account for different table access operators like an index seek or scan. If you have multiple indexes on the tables it gets even more complex than that. (For more information on the different join types and join operators check out my join series: http://sqlity.net/en/1146/a-join-a-day-introduction/)

Now if you have a three table join between A, B, C there are six ways to order the tables and 3 options for the two join operators each totaling 54 ways to create a plan just looking at the join operators and the table order. That is an almost ten-fold increase. For six tables there are almost 200-thousand options and for eight tables almost 100-million. Again, that is only the table order and the join operators and does not account for potential indexes and table access methods.

Instead of trying to go through all plans which could take a lot longer that actually executing the query, SQL Server looks only at a few based on heuristics and rules that are supported by statistics of each table's data. Those heuristics are generally very good and usually SQL Server finds a plan that is very close to the best possible one. However, there are cases were this process falls appart. This is particularly likely to happen if the statistics are out of date.

So, the first thing to look at are those statistics. If that does not help, try adding filtered statistics and filtered indexes. If you are on enterprise you could create indexed views to pre-calculate some fo the joins. (Standard edition won't use indexed views unless you explicitly tell it too.)

After that you could look at providing join hints to help SQL Server in coming up with a good plan.

If all that does not help, split the query into smaller parts and store the intermediate results in temporary objects. Using #temp_tables is generally better in such a case as @table_variables don't have statistics, so their use can hurt the next step.

Comment: Thanks for deep analysis. I'll try to apply your tips and post the results.

Answer (score 1):

Your two queries are not the same.  The first is storing part of the results in a table variable.  The second is including it in the query.

The execution plans are almost necessarily different.  To understand the differences, you need to look at the query plan.

Here are some possible reasons why the performance might be different from what you expect:

- Perhaps the overhead of returning rows from the database is simply greater than the overhead of inserting into a table.
- The SQL query may have more information about the table variable when it compiles, because the table variable is already created when the second part is compiled.
- The combined query may just choose a poor execution plan, even if all the statistics are updated.  That is, doing the "P2" query together may be optimal, but it may choose another plan.